# PATH setup in Zsh in OS X

Tags: zsh, path, macos

I have the following in my notes from some research that I did in Zsh in OS X in the past.

> Between `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zshrc`, OSX seems to call `/etc/.zprofile` which calls `path_helper`, which itself **recreates** `PATH` using `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`

The above seems to suggest that if I want to use my own `PATH` for `non-interative` Zsh shells, I should **not** make those modifications in `.zshenv`.

This is odd, because those paths above (`/etc/.zprofile` `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`) are not **user** files and they **reset** PATH

1. What exact dot files does Zsh load in OS X?
2. What's the role of those path locations (e.g. `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`), and are they unique to OSX?
3. What's the recommended practice for setting up PATH for a shell like in Zsh in OSX?

Comment: I think the most straightforward way (and the one I'm using) is putting all the environment variables in `.zshenv` and `sudo rm /etc/zprofile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The same as any other Zsh installation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files
2. Those are unique to macOS and are used by `/etc/zprofile` to populate your `$path`/`$PATH`.
3. You don't really need to do anything by default on macOS. Everything `$path`-related is already set up by `/etc/zprofile`. If you do have additional dirs you need to add to your `$path`, then I recommend adding something like this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

   ```bsh
   typeset -U PATH path
   path=( 
       ~/Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.55/bin 
       /usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin 
       $path[@]
   )
   ```

   This puts my specific dirs before the rest of `$path`, making sure they get searched first and `-U` ensures that `$path` doesn't have any duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks - in answer #2 you said: _"those are unique to macOS"_ and then in #1 _"[In macOS, Zsh uses] the same [dot files] as any other Zsh installation"_. By dot files I was referring more holistically to configuration files (even if granted the macOS path `/etc/paths.d` does not start with '.' per se). Are there any other configuration files that macOS loads when it starts Zsh that are unique to macOS?

Comment: By default, macOS comes packaged with these three Zsh dotfiles in `/etc/`: `zprofile`, `zshrc` and `zshrc_Apple_Terminal`. That last one is unique to macOS, but is in no way special; it's not loaded automatically by Zsh, but simply sourced from `/etc/zshrc`. `/etc/paths` & `/etc/paths.d/` are used by `/usr/libexec/path_helper` to set your `$PATH`, which is called from `/etc/zprofile`. `path_helper ` is unique to macOS, but not specific to Zsh; it simply generates paths for C shells & Bourne shells.